# current source feature

Tags: current-source

I'm blanking out on a name for something about current source circuit B in this imageSomewhere, i
[image]

Somewhere in some forum thread in the last year there was a discussion about errors in current source circuits.  IIRC there is a mod to circuit B that adds a resistor in series with one of the bases.

1. Is this in fact a known fix to reduce the effects of xxx (base current, temperature drift, whatever)?
2. Does the error effect or this correction have a name, like "adding the resistor reduces the Wolfgang effect".

Update:  Vague memory of it being some kind of effect that had to do with the transistor itself, maybe beginning with an "E" - ?

Thanks.

ak

Comment: Maybe "wolfgang" = [Widlar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widlar_current_source).